# How can I make .replace(/./g, '_') work with exceptions for spaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made my first Jquery project, a simple hangman game that uses one word book titles in the word bank. I would like to expand it to work with multi-word titles, but I'm am not finding the info to adjust my code.

Currently it searches the word bank for a random word and replaces letters with underscores using:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
      return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}

function setup(theWord) {
  word = theWord.toUpperCase();
  remainingletters = word;
  secret = word.replace(/./g, '_');
  $('#secret').text(secret);
}
```

What is a way I can write it out to ignore replacing the spaces and leaving those essentially solved for the user?

https://github.com/jasonboru/hangman.git

Comment: `[^ ]` instead of `.`? `[^…]` is a [negated character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets).

Answer (score 0):

You could do 
`secret = word.replace(/\w/g, '_');`

This would replace word characters with underscores, leaving whitespace and other punctuation visible.